# Подсветка цифр в массиве

Tags: java, c++, python, c, алгоритм

У меня имеется массив чисел от 0 до 100 с повторениями. Длина массива N>100, например.
Необходимо в зависимости от значения цифры изменить ее цвет.

Какие существуют изящные способы решения этой задачи без привязки к ЯП ну или с привязкой к Python?

Пусть `value` - это значение элемента в массиве.

Можно написать что-то типа:

```
def func(value):
    if value>0 and value<=10:
        color='blue'
    if value>10 and value<=20:
        color='green'
    ...
    if value>90 and value<=100:
        color='yellow'
    return color
```

Но такое решение кажется мне не верным и долгим.

Comment: Делаем массив из всех цветов. Делаем `(value + 1) / 10` (с округлением вниз). Достаем цвет по этому индексу...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общие решение (т. к. константы `LIMITS` и `COLORS` возможно приспособить):

```
LIMITS = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
COLORS = "blue green red white orange black magenta purple brown yellow".split()


def func(val):
    for limit, color in zip(LIMITS, COLORS):
        if val <= limit:
            return color
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

---

Или то-же самое с использованием словаря:

```
COLORS = {10: "blue",  20: "green",   30: "red",    40: "white",  50: "orange",
          60: "black", 70: "magenta", 80: "purple", 90: "brown", 100: "yellow"}


def func(val):
    for limit in COLORS:
        if val <= limit:
            return COLORS[limit]
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

---

Или - опять то-же самое - с использованием модуля `enum` (Питон 3.4+):

```
from enum import IntEnum


class Color(IntEnum):
    blue    =  10
    green   =  20
    red     =  30
    white   =  40
    orange  =  50
    black   =  60
    magenta =  70
    purple  =  80
    brown   =  90
    yellow  = 100


def func(val):
    for color, limit in Color.__members__.items():
        if val <= limit:
            return color
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

Comment: Можно обойтись без цикла воспользовавшись целочисленным делением числа на 10. Только номера цветов в словаре должны начинаться с 0,1,2,...